# Media keys on Keyboard don't work during games

Tags: games, media, keys

How do I make media keys work during fullscreen game play? The media keys on my keyboard i.e volume up, volume down, mute don't work during game play. If I want to adjust the volume I have to exit the game, adjust volume,and return to the game. They work on media apps such as Rhythmbox, Vlc, Qmmp, Audacious just not on games like Armagetronad, Chromium BSU, Flobopuyo, Frozen Bubble, SuperTuxkart. I have Googled and found many similar issues but no solutions. Please help.